# Drawable view background with gradient showing correctly in preview but not in emulator

Tags: android, xml, view, background, drawable

I want to create a divider like view which fades to the edges. Therfore I've created a drawable shape with a gradient to both sides which I am setting as Background of a View. In my XML preview my desired result is shown but when I launch the App in the emulator the drawable is rotated 90 degreese and I dont know why that is.

This is my shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/white"
        android:endColor="@color/transparent"
        android:startColor="@color/transparent"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

this is my view

```
<View
     android:layout_width="256dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:background="@drawable/horizontal_fading_divider"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recycler_view"
     android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
```

[This is how it should look like (Preview)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z51un.png)

[This is how it actually looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9HTV.png)

Comment: use angle property in gradient

Comment: My shape is rotated correctly because I want to have a horizontal gradient and therfore i do not need an angle. Even if I use one nothing changes.

Comment: @Niceumang You were right, thanks! I did have to use the angle property but not with 90 degrees but with 0 degrees?! I thought this would be the standard but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer thanks to Nice umang.

You have to use the angle property even thought you dont want to rotate your shape to be safe it wont be rotated elsewhere.

Like so

```
android:angle="0"
```